# A large-scale, revisioned webpage archive

Tags: database, full-text-search, archive, large-files

I want to test my html-based search engine and I want a relatively large set of revisioned documents. Is there an archive that I could download it and put it in my system? I've read about Wikipedia dumps but I'm not sure how are they formatted. The Intenet Archive's Wayback Machine is good but the servers are slow. I'm looking for an archive that:

- Is large but not huge. Something like 1000 documents with 1000 revisions each would satisfy my project. I'm not looking for 5-terabyte DB.
- Is revisioned. An static, single revision archive won't be good enough.
- I'm looking for documents that are either HTML or could be easily converted to HTML.